# sorting based on date and time in flex

Tags: sorting, date, apache-flex

here i used the sort function for date and time,but it's only sort on date not time,i want sort based on both date and time:

```
    private function dregdate_sortCompareFuction(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int {
            var dt1:Date  = DateField.stringToDate(String(itemA.sbatchregdate),"DD/MM/YYYY");
            var dt2:Date  = DateField.stringToDate(String(itemB.sbatchregdate),"DD/MM/YYYY");               
            var dateA:Date = new Date(dt1);             
            var dateB:Date = new Date(dt2);         
            return ObjectUtil.dateCompare(dateA, dateB);}
```

kindly please share your knowledge.
thanks

Comment: if your input contains only a date, as your input format in the stringToDate method suggests, all the Date objects created will have the time set at 00:00.

What's the content of the sbatchregdate property? does it contain the time information as well? in which format

Comment: yes my sbatchregdate contains  28/07/2016 12:55 this format(date and time)so i want to sort by date with time

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by the format you're passing, DateField.stringToDate only cares about dates and not times.

You could use Date.parse if your input string was in one of these formats:

- MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TZD
- HH:MM:SS TZD Day Mon/DD/
- Mon DD YYYY HH:MM:SS
- Day Mon DD HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY
- Day DD Mon HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY
- Mon/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TZD
- YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS TZD

but yours is not.

So give this, i'd use a Regular Expression to extract the individual values from the string and then build the Date object manually, something like:

```
var regex:RegExp = /^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)$/i;
var data:Object = regex.exec(itemA.sbatchregdate);
var dateA:Date = new Date(o[3], o[2]-1, o[1], o[4], o[5]);
```

once you have the two dates created with the proper time values, the comparison should work as expected.